# Convert a large number, from Base 256 to Base 10

Tags: c#, delphi, numbers, radix

I need to convert very large numbers from Base 256 (bytes) to Base 10 (decimal) in C# or Delphi.
The actual goal is to represent contents of any given file as a very large decimal number and save it in a txt file, for example. We all know how to convert from one base to another, but the real challenge here is the size of the number.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since when is Base 256 binary? Binary is Base 2

Comment: What have you tried and just out of curiosity, why? Its not any more efficient  to store data using the full character set because all those are just in turn stored as binary

Comment: @DiMono, sorry I didn't mean 0 and 1. I meant contents of a binary file. Edited the question.

Comment: A Delphi/Pascal library handling big integers base 2-255 with millions of digits can be found here: [`TBigNum`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigint/).

Comment: That's a somewhat odd approach. More common would be to use base64. Why select base 10?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, We want to do some math operations.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy Math operations? Converting contents of a file to a number sounds like a hash operation. You're getting lots of questions because it's hard for people to fathom why you're attempting this operation and many feel that if they understood what you were trying to accomplish, they might be able to recommend a better process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I strongly suspect that if you're using .NET 4 or higher, you'll be able to use the [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207.aspx) constructor - and then convert the result to a decimal string if you want to (or just use it *as a number*). You may need to reverse the bytes in the input array depending on the endianness of your input.

Comment: I'm happy that there are generous, professional programmers on this website, whose aim is to help others. Instead of poking fun at the askers, or looking for their ponies. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

As of your update, this is pretty straightforward.

It sounds like you're trying to read the binary file in terms of chars, using some getc() function (the exact name escapes me). Every char is represented by one byte, hence 256 options. This gives chars a certain level of permeability with 8 bit ints. You should be able to read in a character and cast it to an integer, which will give you the decimal representation of the character's 8 bits.

Also chars aren't base 256, they're just 8 bit binary numbers.

Comment: Nope. Whole content as a number.

Comment: My mistake, thought you were just trying to read in the file in 8 bit chunks.

Comment: @Delphi Boy:  So, if your file contains N bytes, you want to treat its contents as an 8 * N bit binary number, and then convert that to its decimal representation, is that it?